# blacklist command not found in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nouveau, blacklist

I am trying to use the command blacklist on my laptop which is Dell precision. I have Ubuntu 16.04 on it.

It shows the error below:

```
No command 'blacklist' found, did you mean:
command 'zblacklist' from package 'zmap' (universe)
blacklist command not found
```

Any advice what I must do....

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Comment: trying to blacklist the nouveau driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To black list a module or driver you don't have to use a command "blacklist".

Open this file (Create it if it does not exist):

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

add a line like this:

```
blacklist nouveau
```

save the file, reboot the system. You can use `modprobe -r nouveau` to remove it temporary.